# Is it normal that PolyLine cable is so twisty?

Tags: wiring

Is it normal that PolyLine "cable" is so wound up? Not sure the right word but it's like twisted strands that if you try and straighten them out the strands start separating but otherwise the line is all twisty.

[image]

This is nothing that's going to sit nice in a wall like a regular string would though this is what many recommend to run thru the wall in case you need to run something later.
[image]

Comment: That's normal..

Comment: Thanks so this will sit all squiggly if that's a word in my wall?  How is this better than a straight string?  The strength or something?

Comment: Finding thin, strong string that is also straight is tough. Fishing line line does the same thing. What straight string do you have in mind that is just as thin and just as strong?

Comment: Yeah I'm kind of funny that way.  Like everything clean and having this cord kind of looped up in the wall bothers me.  Plus I could see other cables getting hung up on it in the future.  Maybe in my case, I have to tie it off in the attic (once I get there) to a rafter, and then pull it a bit in the basement and tie it off.  Make me feel better that it's straighter.

Comment: You could try running it through a cup of boiling hot water to relax it.